# Training a BARTForSequenceClassification returns data with ununiform dimentsions

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am  trying to fine-tune a BART-base model on a dataset that I have. The dataset looks like this: It has columns "id", "text", "label" and "dataset_id". The "text" column is what I want to use as inputs to the model, and it is plain text. "label" is a value of either 0 or 1.

I've already written the code for Training, using transfomers==4.28.0.

This is the code for the dataset class:

```
class TextDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, encodings):
        self.encodings = encodings

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return {key: torch.tensor(val[idx]) for key, val in self.encodings.items()}

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.encodings['input_ids'])
```

This is the code for loading and encoding of the data:

```
def load_data(directory):
    files = os.listdir(directory)
    dfs = []
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('train.csv'):
            df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(directory, file))
            dfs.append(df)
    return pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
print(len(load_data("splitted_data/gender-bias")))

def encode_data(tokenizer, text, labels):
    inputs = tokenizer(text, padding="max_length", truncation=True, max_length=128, return_tensors="pt")
    inputs['labels'] = torch.tensor(labels)
    return inputs
```

This is the code for the metrics for evaluation. I use the f1_score function from scikit.

```
def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    logits = eval_pred.predictions
    labels = eval_pred.label_ids
    predictions = np.argmax(logits, axis=-1)
    return {"f1": f1_score(labels, predictions)}
```

This is the training function:

```
def train_model(train_dataset, eval_dataset):
    # Define the training arguments
    training_args = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir='./baseline/results',           # output directory
        num_train_epochs=5,               # total number of training epochs
        per_device_train_batch_size=32,   # batch size per device during training
        per_device_eval_batch_size=64,    # batch size for evaluation
        warmup_steps=500,                 # number of warmup steps for learning rate scheduler
        weight_decay=0.01,                # strength of weight decay
        evaluation_strategy="steps",      # evaluation is done at each training step
        eval_steps=50,                    # number of training steps between evaluations
        load_best_model_at_end=True,      # load the best model when finished training (defaults to `False`)
        save_strategy='steps',            # save the model after each training step
        save_steps=500,                   # number of training steps between saves
        metric_for_best_model='f1',       # metric to use to compare models
        greater_is_better=True            # whether a larger metric value is better
    )

    # Define the trainer
    trainer = Trainer(
        model=model,
        args=training_args,
        train_dataset=train_dataset,
        eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
        compute_metrics=compute_metrics
    )

    # Train the model
    trainer.train()

    return trainer
```

This is how I defined the model and etc.

```
model = BartForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('facebook/bart-base', num_labels=2)
tokenizer = BartTokenizer.from_pretrained('facebook/bart-base')

train_df = load_data("splitted_data/gender-bias")
train_encodings = encode_data(tokenizer, train_df['text'].tolist(), train_df['label'].tolist())

# For simplicity, let's split our training data to create a pseudo-evaluation set
train_size = int(0.9 * len(train_encodings['input_ids']))  # 90% for training
train_dataset = {k: v[:train_size] for k, v in train_encodings.items()}
print(train_dataset)
print(len(train_dataset))

eval_dataset = {k: v[train_size:] for k, v in train_encodings.items()}  # 10% for evaluation

# Convert the dictionary data to PyTorch Dataset
train_dataset = TextDataset(train_dataset)
eval_dataset = TextDataset(eval_dataset)

trainer = train_model(train_dataset, eval_dataset)
```

The training looks just fine. However, when it comes to evaluation during training, an error is raised from my compute_metrics function, which takes a parameter as the output of the model. The model should be a binary classification model, returning the probabilistic of each label in its output I believe.

```
np.argmax(np.array(logits), axis=-1) 21 
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3208,2) into shape (3208,)
```

I've tried to output the type of the logits, and it turns out that `type(logits)` return `Tuple`. Considering that this might be caused the fact that evaluation dataset might be split into batches, and the returned Tuple is a number of separate numpy arrays, I've also tried to concatenate the tuple.

```
def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    logits = eval_pred.predictions
    labels = eval_pred.label_ids
    logits = np.concatenate(logits, axis=0)
    predictions = np.argmax(logits, axis=-1)
    return {"f1": f1_score(labels, predictions)}
```

But this raised a new error:

```
packages/numpy/core/overrides.py in concatenate(*args, **kwargs) 

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 3 dimension(s)
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `I've tried to output the type of the logits, and it turns out that type(logits) return Tuple.` What's the shape of each element of the tuple? e.g if you add `print([l.shape for l in logits])`, what does that print?

Comment: @NickODell Thanks for your reply! The Output looks like this: `[(3208, 2), (3208, 128, 768)]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. Since the returned tuple has a shape of `[(3208, 2), (3208, 128, 768)]`, it is returning two things simultaneously. The first element of this tuple represents the binary logits for the predictions, while the second element seems to be an output of a layer of my BART model. Hence, the code works well when I write it as below:

```
def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    logits = eval_pred.predictions[0]
    labels = eval_pred.label_ids
    predictions = np.argmax(logits, axis=-1)
    return {"f1": f1_score(labels, predictions)}
```